# Storyboard: still "Unable to write to path" after deleting folder in Derived Data

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard

Here's the exact error

```
/Users/colesmith/Desktop/ui/Sysco/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard: Compilation failed. Unable to write to path: /Users/colesmith/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sysco-ezcmchmwlezfctayjgelgubgjqsg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sysco.app/Base.lproj/Main.storyboardc
```

I've tried everything. Even adding in a new storyboard and replacing it with my existing one. I've tried cleaning the project, and I've tried new schemes, and deleting the folder in DerivedData with no luck. I also repaired disk permissions.

This started randomly when I was working. I got the error one build and haven't been able to resolve it.

The storyboard contains hours of work and would be devastating to lose. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Can you please try pointing to new Derived Data folder and also exit Xcode and re-open project again

Comment: I actually was able to fix this by changing some of the storyboard IDs for some view controllers. I wasn't able to find the exact issue and it seems to be a bug on apple's end.

Answer (score 0):

Cole's answer is correct!
I also encountered similar problem. One my view controller have storyboard ID: "Mega6/45VC". I fixed by change to "MegaVC". Maybe,problem is character "/".

Answer (score 0):

**This Fix for me:** Go to **Build phases -> Copy bundle resources** , Look for Duplicate story board, If there is more than one storyboard appears then remove one it will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just reran the project with ⌘ + b and it worked.